# What are the "standard conditions" for existence and uniqueness of solutions for a dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading 
http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa02/caltech/mls93-lyap.pdf

There's a specific passage where the authors introduce Lyapunov stability and equilibrium points.

[image]

They say "standard conditions." What are these? Is the list provided in the passage complete or are there more conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions mentioned are satisfied, then the solution of the differential equation exists and is unique. However, there are cases where these conditions are not satisfied, and still the solution is unique. Thus, $\text{given conditions} \implies \text{uniqueness}$, but not vice versa.